# What does ESP mean in assembly?

Tags: architecture, syntax, assembly, preprocessor, cpu-registers

```
ESP = ? stack pointer
```

What does **E** stand for here?

**UPDATE**

RSP for 64bit?

What does `R` mean here?

Comment: It took 4 minutes to get an answer here.  Google would have taken seconds.  "esp stack pointer"

Comment: @Anonymouse: well, to be pedantic - only 2 minutes between the question and the first answer by `codeaddict`

Comment: @EliBendersky ironically, this is now the first result for that Google query. I bet it's repaid the author's original time loss by the hundreds of thousands by now. Well, not the author's - but everyone else's!

Answer (score 17):

`E` stands for `Extended`

> With the advent of the 32-bit 80386 processor, the 16-bit general-purpose registers, base registers, index registers, instruction pointer, and FLAGS register, but not the segment registers, were expanded to 32 bits. This is represented by prefixing an **"E" (for Extended)** to the register names in x86 assembly language.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#32-bit)

Answer (score 4):

R is just for "register", with the new registers called just r8-r15. Since the old ones also needed names for their extended versions, the e was just swapped to r.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps for consistency with the other 32-bit registers: `EAX`, `EBX` etc.

For those, `E` means "extended" - i.e. to 32 bits (the 16-bit versions are called `AX`, `BX` etc.)

P.S. according to [The Free Dictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/Extended+Stack+Pointer), `ESP` stands for Extended Stack Pointer.

Comment: The SP doesn't have an 8 bit version but AX, BX, CX, and DX do, they are known as AL, AH, BL, BH, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

E means Extended. If you have SP 16bit, so ESP should be 32bit.

Comment: And for completion's sake, RSP for 64bit.

Comment: R as in register. Compare r8,r9...