# What do the E and R prefixes stand for in the names of Intel 32-bit and 64-bit registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, cpu-registers

The 32-bit register names start with an E and the 64-bit ones start with an R. What do the E and R stand for? Is there a reason for choosing these alphabets?

Also, in 64-bit registers, too, we can see in any low-level debugger such as Windbg that the right-most bits are still referred to by the same name as that of the 64-bit register except the name starts with an E. For e.g. the right-most 32 bits of the RAX register in a 64-bit system is referred to as EAX.

So, do the E and R stand for something? And also, why the suffix X for register?

Comment: Partially at least http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125729/where-can-i-find-x86-register-names

Comment: `E` means extended http://stackoverflow.com/a/1753618/995714 [What does the 'R' in x64 register names stand for?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/127668/98103). [What does X mean in EAX,EBX,ECX…?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2545226/995714). [What does E in ESP mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2537367/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I'm closing some of the older questions as duplicates of this, when appropriate.  This looks like it has the most canonical answer, especially since it sources the "R" naming to that mailing list post by an AMD architect.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

- [`R` just stands for "**r**egister"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127668/what-does-the-r-in-x64-register-names-stand-for). The AMD64 ISA extension added 8 additional general-purpose registers, named `R8` through `R15`. The 64-bit extended versions of the original 8 registers had an `R` prefix added to them [for symmetry](http://web.archive.org/web/20140413211300/http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2000-September/000283.html).
- `E` stands for "**e**xtended" or "**e**nhanced". ([Wikipedia says "**e**xtended"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2537380/224132).) They are the "extended" versions of the 16-bit registers, in that they offer 16 additional bits for 32 bits total.
- `X` is also for "e**x**tended"—or perhaps it implies 16 as in he**x**adecimal.<sup>*</sup> The `X`-suffixed registers are the 16-bit extended versions of the 8-bit registers. For 8-bit registers, the `L` suffix means "low", and the `H` suffix means "high".

Therefore, taking one particular register as an example, you have the 8-bit `AL` and `AH` registers, which are the low and high bytes of the 16-bit `AX` register, which is the low word of the 32-bit `EAX` register, which is the low double-word of the 64-bit `RAX` register.

```
| 63 - 32 | 31 - 16 | 15 - 8 | 7 - 0 |
======================================
.         .         | AH     | AL    |
.         .         | AX             |
.         | EAX                      | 
| RAX                                |
======================================
| 63 - 32 | 31 - 16 | 15 - 8 | 7 - 0 |
```

__
<sub>* [`X` was used in the mnemonics (such as `LXI` and `DCX`) on the 8080](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565092/224132) for [instructions that treated a pair of otherwise-separate 8-bit registers as a 16-bit integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080#16-bit_operations), similar to how `AX` represents the `AH:AL` pair. Thus, another possible interpretation is that `X` means *pair*, and this usage was continued when naming the high:low pairs on subsequent processors, including the 8086, which was a full 16-bit extension of the 8080.</sub>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565092/224132 suggests that the X may stand for "pair".  8080, an ancestor of 8086, could use pairs of 8-bit registers as a 16-bit integer or pointer the same way that CX is the CH:CL register-pair.

Comment: Thanks, good find. While I agree that's an interesting historical tidbit worth incorporating into a canonical answer, I'm not sure it convinces me that "X" actually stands for "pair". It probably still stood for "extended", since these instructions were "extended" to operate on 16-bit pairs. @Peter

Comment: Yeah, while editing your answer after leaving my first comment, I decided it probably means / comes from pair but doesn't literally stand for it.  IDK if I.J. Kennedy really meant to say it *stood for* pair, or just meant to illustrate the 8080 history.

Comment: Also related: [Why are first four x86 GPRs named in such unintuitive order?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5121) has some good stuff about how designing 8086 for easy source-porting from 8080 asm influenced the design of the register set.

Comment: Related: writing AL, AH, or AX just merge a new value into that low part of RAX.  Writing EAX zero-extends into the full RAX.  [How do AX, AH, AL map onto EAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191178)