# GDB - Reading 1 words from the stack

Tags: gdb, x86-64

I want to print 1 words from the top of stack in the form of hexadecimal. To do so, I typed the following:

`(gdb) x/1xw $esp`

but GDB keeps popping up:

`0xffffffffffffe030:     Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffe030`

The program I'm trying to debug has already pushed a value onto stack so just in case if you're wondering that I might be trying to access kernel variables at the very beginning of program, it's not so.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xffffffffffffe030` is a 64-bit constant, so you are running in x64-bit mode. But `$esp` is a 32-bit register (which GDB sign-extends to 64 bits in this context).  The 64-bit stack pointer is called `$rsp`.  Try this instead:

```
(gdb) x/1xw $rsp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Just one little thing I'd like to know. What does 'r' in rax, rsp or any other 64 bit register stands for? 32 bit registers are preceded with an 'e' which stands for 'extended'.

Comment: @7_R3X: [What do the E and R prefixes stand for in the names of Intel 32-bit and 64-bit registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933379/what-do-the-e-and-r-prefixes-stand-for-in-the-names-of-intel-32-bit-and-64-bit-r)

Comment: @ecm: Thanks a lot!