# Segmentation fault when writing assembly version of reference operator

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I am attempting to mimic the following C code in assembly:

```
int x = 12;
int *y = &x;
int z = *y;
```

I have the following:

```
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 16

mov DWORD [rbp - 4], 12
lea eax, [rbp - 4]
mov DWORD [rbp - 8], eax
mov eax, DWORD [rbp - 8]
mov edi, DWORD [eax]
```

However, I receive a segmentation fault when calling the last line of assembly. Am I missing another layer of indirection?

Comment: Don't truncate pointers to 32-bit.  `lea eax, [rbp - 4]` - take the 64-bit stack address and truncate it to 32-bit.  `mov edi, [eax]` override the address size to 32-bit, using the low half of RAX.  RSP is a 64-bit register, and on normal OSes is outside the low 4GiB.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes that makes sense. I've fixed it by ensuring my pointers are the correct size and data type.

Comment: Looking for a duplicate now; I'm sure this isn't new.  That's why I answered in comments.

Comment: Does `mov edi, DWORD [eax]` make sense in a 64 bit environment, `eax` being a 32 bit value?

Comment: [What do the E and R prefixes stand for in the names of Intel 32-bit and 64-bit registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43933379) is related if you didn't realize that EAX is a 32-bit register.  Didn't manage to turn up an exact duplicate with google.