# Assembly: Memory address of variables in C Programming

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, ollydbg

This is my C code

```
C:\Codes>gdb test -q
Reading symbols from C:\Codes\test.exe...done.
(gdb) list 1,15
1       #include<stdio.h>
2
3       int main()
4       {
5               int a = 12345;
6               int b = 0x12345;
7               printf("+-----+-------+---------+----------+\n");
8               printf("| Var | Dec   | Hex     | Address  |\n");
9               printf("+-----+-------+---------+----------+\n");
10              printf("|  a  | %d | 0x%x  | %p |\n",a,a,&a);
11              printf("|  b  | %d | 0x%x | %p |\n",b,b,&b);
12              printf("+-----+-------+---------+----------+\n");
13
14              return 0;
15      }
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
```

And this is the standard output

```
C:\Codes>test
+-----+-------+---------+----------+
| Var | Dec   | Hex     | Address  |
+-----+-------+---------+----------+
|  a  | 12345 | 0x3039  | 0022FF4C |
|  b  | 74565 | 0x12345 | 0022FF48 |
+-----+-------+---------+----------+
```

This is what I'm seeing in GDB

```
(gdb) break 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40135e: file test.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Codes/test.exe
[New Thread 4044.0xab0]

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:7
7               printf("+-----+-------+---------+----------+\n");
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00401340 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x00401341 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x00401343 <+3>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x00401346 <+6>:     sub    esp,0x20
   0x00401349 <+9>:     call   0x401990 <__main>
   0x0040134e <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x3039
   0x00401356 <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x12345
=> 0x0040135e <+30>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403024
   0x00401365 <+37>:    call   0x401c00 <puts>
   0x0040136a <+42>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x40304c
   0x00401371 <+49>:    call   0x401c00 <puts>
   0x00401376 <+54>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403024
   0x0040137d <+61>:    call   0x401c00 <puts>
   0x00401382 <+66>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
   0x00401386 <+70>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
   0x0040138a <+74>:    lea    ecx,[esp+0x1c]
   0x0040138e <+78>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],ecx
   0x00401392 <+82>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],edx
   0x00401396 <+86>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
   0x0040139a <+90>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403071
   0x004013a1 <+97>:    call   0x401c08 <printf>
   0x004013a6 <+102>:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x18]
   0x004013aa <+106>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x18]
   0x004013ae <+110>:   lea    ecx,[esp+0x18]
   0x004013b2 <+114>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],ecx
   0x004013b6 <+118>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],edx
   0x004013ba <+122>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
   0x004013be <+126>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x40308c
   0x004013c5 <+133>:   call   0x401c08 <printf>
   0x004013ca <+138>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403024
   0x004013d1 <+145>:   call   0x401c00 <puts>
   0x004013d6 <+150>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x004013db <+155>:   leave
   0x004013dc <+156>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

The address for variables `a` & `b` is supposed to be at `0x22ff4c` & `0x22ff48` respectively

```
(gdb) print &a
$1 = (int *) 0x22ff4c

(gdb) print &b
$2 = (int *) 0x22ff48
```

However, if you look at the following GDB disassemble output, the address was not `0x22ff4c` & `0x22ff48`, but `0x0040134e` & `0x00401356`

```
   0x0040134e <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x3039
   0x00401356 <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x12345
```

I've also debug this on x32dbg but getting the same address too.
[image: x32dbg]

I'm confused here. What was the `0x0040134e` & `0x00401356` if they are not the memory addresses for variables `a` & `b`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
0x0040134e <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x3039
0x00401356 <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x12345
```

No, `0x0040134e` and `0x00401356` are not addresses for variables `a` and `b`. Instead they are address of the instruction in code, i.e. [instruction pointer IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter). `a` and `b` are initialized in these lines:

```
0x0040134e <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x3039
0x00401356 <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x12345
```

Here the address of `a` and `b` are `esp+0x1c` and `esp+0x18` respectively  where `esp` is the [stack pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537367/what-does-esp-mean-in-assembly). As address you are getting `0x22ff4c` and `0x22ff48` from which you can easily deduct that current `esp` is `0x22ff4c - 0x1c`.

Please note the this answer ignores the underlying virtual memory management or other related memory management matters of operating system, i.e. on most architecture `0x22ff4c` and `0x22ff48` will be virtual memory address, not the real physical address of your RAM.